# Java - Updating Window Overlay

Tags: java, user-interface, paintcomponent

I would like to create a transparent window which overlays the desktop and displays the current system time.  I have been trying to work with the following code:

```
Window w=new Window(null)
{
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
      ...
  }
};
w.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
w.setBounds(w.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds());
w.setBackground(new Color(0, true));
w.setVisible(true);
```

However, I can not get `repaint()` to work as the window only updates once.  I don't really understand how this works and I can't find out how to update the window components outside of the paint method.  The window doesn't display until the paint method has already been completed, and then I can not use `repaint()` again.  I know I'm missing something here, Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do custom painting. Just add a JLabel to the window and then set the text with the time information.

Then you can use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the updates of the label.

Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTime extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel timeLabel;
    private int count = 0;

    public TimerTime()
    {
        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        add( timeLabel );

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //System.out.println(e.getSource());
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );
//      timeLabel.setText( String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() ) );
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);

        if (count == 10)
        {
            Timer timer = (Timer)e.getSource();
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerTime");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TimerTime() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that this was more of a proof-of-concept thing.  In the final program there will be squares overlaid on the screen corresponding to a chess board which change based on the piece last moved... so unfortunately I do believe I need a paintcomponent

Comment: @ScottSinischo, That is NOT what your question states. It states `I would like to create a transparent window which overlays the desktop and displays the current system time.` - this has absolutely nothing to do with a chess board. We are not mind readers, we can't guess what you are really asking. Post a proper question in the forum so we don't waste time!!!